# Get position of DOM element relative to top of the page with Javascript (Cross-Browser)

Tags: javascript, dom, position

I'm having an issue in trying to determine the position of a DOM element relative to the top of the page (whether in or out of the viewport).

Now, in **Firefox**, this is very easy, just do:

`jQuery(element).offset().top`

In **Chrome**, however, that expression returns the position of the element relative to the viewport, which changes as I scroll up and down the page. In that case, I can instead calculate the value I want by doing:

`jQuery(element).offset().top + document.body.scrollTop`

The difficulty is, of course, that different versions of Chrome might deal with this differently, not to speak of other browsers I can't even test! Is there a cross-browser simple solution to find this value? It would seem like a simple enough thing to want to do.

**Edit**

As somebody helpfully pointed out, "this should be the same, that's the point of jQuery." I tested it on other websites, and this is so. Somehow, my website is throwing it off for some reason. Any clues of what might be causing this?

Comment: No, Chrome and Firefox behave the same way with `.offset()`. (That's the whole point of jQuery.) However, Chrome (WebKit in general) doesn't like thinking about the `<body>` as part of the scrolling context.

Comment: If you put a `<div>` as the only child of `<body>` with `height: 100%` and make sure you clear any `<body>` padding etc, you can use that `<div>` as the scroll reference element.

Comment: Hello Pointy, you are right, this shouldn't be the case, but somehow it is. .offset().top works as expected in other websites... somehow my website is throwing it off. Any clue of what could be causing this?

Comment: Well I have no idea what your HTML and CSS looks like, so I can't say.

Comment: Actually, you helped a lot by confirming that "the point of jQuery" was that it should return the same value in both browsers. It made me stop looking for cross-browser solutions, but rather try to figure what was wrong with the HTML/CSS. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! As it turns out, there was a strange CSS rule to this effect:

```
html, body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

That was creating a scroll-window inside a scroll-window (but somehow, hidden from view) which means that, even though I was scrolling down through the inner, 'body' window, my viewport wasn't actually moving. I realized this when noticing that the `window.pageYOffset` was returning always 0.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Webkit is weird about scrolling and `<body>` in ways that I don't fully understand.